# how to send a http patch request with ServiceStack Android Client

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to send a patch request using servicestack android client? if not, can I get the android client cookie to use other HttpClient in android?

```
PatchRequest = new JsonPatchRequest
{
 new JsonPatchElement
 {
  op = "replace",
  path = "timezone",
  value = timezone
 },
 new JsonPatchElement
 {
  op = "replace",
  path = "language",
  value = language
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack Android client doesn't support `JsonPatchRequest` ServiceStack's Android client should only be used to call ServiceStack Services.

But you can iterate all cookies with:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = (CookieManager) CookieHandler.getDefault();
List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieManager.getCookies();
for (HttpCookie cookie: cookies) {
    Log.d(TAG, "cookie name : "+cookie.getName().toString());
}
```